# Propositions vs. boolean values for input validation

Tags: idris

I have the following code:

```
doSomething : (s : String) -> (not (s == "") = True) -> String
doSomething s = ?doSomething

validate : String -> String
validate s = case (not (s == ""))  of
                  False  => s
                  True => doSomething s
```

After checking the input is not empty I would like to pass it to a function which accepts only validated input (not empty Strings).

As far as I understand the validation is taking place during runtime 
but the types are calculated during compile time - thats way it doesn't work. Is there any workaround?

Also while playing with the code I noticed:

```
:t (("la" == "") == True)
"la" == "" == True : Bool
```

But

```
:t (("la" == "") = True)
"la" == "" = True : Type
```

Why the types are different?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't about runtime vs. compile-time, since you are writing two branches in `validate` that take care, statically, of both the empty and the non-empty input cases; at runtime you merely choose between the two.

Your problem is [Boolean blindness](https://existentialtype.wordpress.com/2011/03/15/boolean-blindness/): if you have a value of type `Bool`, it is just that, a single bit that could have gone either way. This is what `==` gives you.

`=` on the other hand is for propositional equality: the only constructor of the type(-as-proposition) `a = b` is `Refl : a = a`, so by pattern-matching on a value of type `a = b`, you learn that `a` and `b` are truly equal.

I was able to get your example working by passing the non-equality as a proposition to `doSomething`:

```
doSomething : (s : String) -> Not (s = "") -> String
doSomething "" wtf = void $ wtf Refl
doSomething s nonEmpty = ?doSomething

validate : String -> String
validate "" = ""
validate s = doSomething s nonEmpty
  where
    nonEmpty : Not (s = "")
    nonEmpty Refl impossible
```

Comment: There are two points about "boolean blindness": booleans allow you to cheat equality and "prove" that two things are equal, even if they are not, and booleans lose information. The first claim is silly: setoids allow you to cheat equality as well, but everybody is happy with them. And there is nothing wrong about information forgetting in general. In a dependently typed language you can always recover it. Sometimes it's just needed to erase some type-level stuff (like with heterogeneous equality or lists instead of vectors). It's not "boolean blindness", it's "boolean eyes closing".

Answer (score 1):

> As far as I understand the validation is taking place during runtime
>   but the types are calculated during compile time - thats way it
>   doesn't work.

That's not correct. It doesn't work because

- We need the `with` form to perform dependent pattern matching, i. e. perform substitution and refinement on the context based on information gained from specific data constructors.
- Even if we use `with` here, `not (s == "")` isn't anywhere in the context when we do the pattern match, therefore there's nothing to rewrite (in the context), and we can't demonstrate the `not (s == "") = True` equality later when we'd like to call `doSomething`.

We can use a wrapper data type here that lets us save a proof that a specific pattern equals the original expression we matched on:

```
doSomething : (s : String) -> (not (s == "") = True) -> String
doSomething s = ?doSomething

data Inspect : a -> Type where
  Match : {A : Type} -> {x : A} -> (y : A) -> x = y -> Inspect x

inspect : {A : Type} -> (x : A) -> Inspect x
inspect x = Match x Refl

validate : String -> String
validate s with (inspect (not (s == "")))
  | Match True  p = doSomething s p
  | Match False p = s
```

Comment: Can you explain what you mean about not having `not (s=="")` in the context when you do the pattern matching?

Comment: @dfeuer if we had something  with a type mentioning `not (s  == "")` on the left side of the equation (in OP's `validate`), dependent pattern matching would have to rewrite that to `True` or `False`. If we don't have type dependencies in the context, then pattern matching doesn't give us extra information.